# vuejs with electron, can't use fs

Tags: vue.js, electron, vue-component, fs

I'm using Vue with it's Electron plugin and I want to use fs to read directories, but it gives me this error. What could be the problem?

> TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Component from 'vue-class-component';
import { readdir } from 'fs';

@Component
export default class Directory {
  mounted() {
    readdir('C:/', (err, files) => {
      if (err) console.log(err);
      console.log(files)
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only worked with Angular+Electron combo, but with that I used electron's main process to do file manipulation stuff.

Further read: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main

In the main process, you can access "fs" easily like you would in node.

I don't know if this is the case with Vue, but maybe this helps.

Comment: I've used that combo as well previously and you can actually use fs in components, so I don't want to use IPC for this. Or if it's not gonna work I have to switch back to Angular ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43210136/vue-electron-how-to-write-a-file-to-disk

Comment: happy to help :D